# Can Kisame breathe under water?

Tags: naruto

Can Kisame breathe under water? He's still a shark. He has lungs but those things on his face are branchiae, right?

Answer (score 5):

[Kisame](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kisame_Hoshigaki) having gills on parts of his body means he is likely to be able to

> He has small, round, white eyes, 3 sets of curved facial markings under his eyes, **gills on his shoulders**

However I don't believe Kisame was ever shown being able to inherently breathe underwater (somebody correct me if I am wrong), a majority of fans are speculating that he is able to due this factor and his overall shark-like appearance.

However, later on in the Shippuden series, Kisame is shown being able to breathe underwater when fusing himself with his sword

> When fused with Samehada, he gains the ability to breathe underwater using gills which form on his neck

Comment: "Yes, but only when he fused with Samehada" was going to be my answer.  You're spot on here as well.  Be sure to cite your quotes a bit more concisely.

Answer (score 0):

in the anime when he steals back chakra from Bee after exiting Samehada, its shown that bubbles escape the gills on his shoulders, so they might be functional.